# Загрузка файлов ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть инпут

```
<input class='edit_photo_input_1' id='edit_photo_input_1' type='file' multiple='multiple' accept='image/*' name='upload_photo[]' />
```

Отправляю

```
$('#edit_photo_input_1').bind('change', function(){

    jQuery.each($('#edit_photo_input_1')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/photo_upload/',
            data: {upload_photo:file, set_id:1},
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function() {
                //
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('li.photo_add_li').before(data);
            }
        });

    });

})
```

Ловлю

```
$_POST['set_id'];
$_FILES['upload_photo']['tmp_name'];
```

Хочу получить - input(multiple) - скрипт берет каждый прикрепленный файл и отправляет по очереди - ловлю и обрабатываю каждый файл. Вопрос - как правильно в скрипте взять каждый фаил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот рабочий вариант скрипта, просто я не силен в объектах

```
$('#edit_photo_input_1').bind('change', function(){

    jQuery.each($('#edit_photo_input_1')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('upload_photo', file);
        data.append('set_id', set_id);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/admin/photo_upload/',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что тебе это поможет (тем более, я до конца не понял, что именно у тебя пришло, а что не пришло - ничего не пришло, один ли файл пришел еще ли чего) - но, возможно, хотябы наведет на какую-нибудь мысль: в свое время делал функцию для выгрузки файлов (точнее, немного дорабатывал чью-то чужую

```
submit = function(e){ 

var formObj = $(this);
var formURL = 'http://' +  location.host  + '/kuda/otpravlyaem.php'; // PHP-обработчик 
if(window.FormData !== "undefined")  // for HTML5 browsers
    {
        var formData = new FormData(formObj[0]);
        var fdatas = $(this).serializeArray(); 
        formData.append( 'submit', 1 );

        if (!$('#submit').hasClass('loadingform')){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url :  formURL, // PHP-обработчик 
                data:  formData,
                mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(xhr){  
                    //блокируем от повторного нажатия
                    $('#submit').addClass('loadingform'); 
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { // console.log(data);
                    $('#profile').html(data);
                },
                complete: function(){ // разблокируем
                    $('#submit').removeClass('loadingform');  
                }
            });
        } 
    }
    else  //for olden browsers
    {
        //generate a random id
        var  iframeId = 'unique' + (new Date().getTime());
        //create an empty iframe
        var iframe = $('<iframe src="javascript:false;" name="'+iframeId+'" />');
        //hide it
        iframe.hide();
        //set form target to iframe
        formObj.attr('target',iframeId);

        //Add iframe to body
        iframe.appendTo('body');
        iframe.load(function(e)
            {
                var doc = cyr.Profile.getDoc(iframe[0]);
                var docRoot = doc.body ? doc.body : doc.documentElement;
                var data = docRoot.innerHTML;
                //data is returned from server.
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Может вопрос твой и проще, но я,честно говоря, не совсем понял, что именно у тебя не получилось...

Comment: в $_FILES['upload_photo']['tmp_name']; нет ничего: или $('#edit_photo_input_1')[0].files неправильно или  data: {upload_photo:file}

Comment: Попробуй, как в моем примере, через new FormData и mimeType: 'multipart/form-data', - я, в свое время, где-то в этой области застревал - тоже фал через ajax идти не желал, потом оказалось, что не все так просто. с этой data:. Если не захочет input с несколькими файлами корректно обрабатывать, как вариант, можно предварительно скриптами превратить его в несколько input'ов в каждоом по 1 файле (примерно, как ты делал, но с append('<input....>'))..